# Query Realm get object which have particularly object in a list

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, realm

I think this is a simple solution, but i´m stuck with the best approach.

My Realm Database is made with the objects **POI** and **CATEGORY**. Where a **POI** can have one or multiple object of **CATEGORY**

```
class POI: Object {

  dynamic var id:String = ""
  dynamic var name:String = ""
  dynamic var visited:Bool = false;

  let categories = List<CATEGORY>()

  override static func primaryKey() -> String?
  {
      return "id";
  }
}
```

Later I need to show the number of **POI** that have a particular **CATEGORY**, and the number of **POI** that have a given **CATEGORY** with the boolean visited has true.

Something like this:

```
func getAllVisitedPointsWithCategory(idCategory:String) -> Results<POI>  {

}

func getAllPointsWithCategory(idCategory:String) -> Results<POI>{

}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
func getAllVisitedPointsWithCategory(idCategory:String) -> [POI]  {
    let containingPOI = getAllPointsWithCategory(idCategory)

    return containingPOI.filter({ (poi) -> Bool in
        return poi.visited
    })
}

func getAllPointsWithCategory(idCategory:String) -> [POI] {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let containingPOI = realm.objects(POI).filter({ (poi) -> Bool in
        return poi.categories.contains({ (cat) -> Bool in
            return idCategory == cat.id
        })
    })

    return containingPOI
}
```

It's basically just querying data and filtering the result.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done more concisely and faster by using Realm's query engine rather than filtering the objects individually in Swift:

```
func getAllVisitedPointsWithCategory(idCategory:String) -> Results<POI>  {
  return getAllPointsWithCategory(idCategory).filter("visited = true")
}

func getAllPointsWithCategory(idCategory:String) -> Results<POI>{
  let realm = try! Realm()
  return realm.objects(POI.self).filter("ANY categories.id = %@", idCategory)
}
```